# O que é o Spring MVC?

Tags: java, mvc, spring-mvc, framework

Estou desenvolvendo um projeto java web e estou  usando o **MVC** (Model-view-controller),que  é um padrão de arquitetura de software (design pattern) e sei que sua função é separar a representação da informação da interação do usuário com ela.
Então minha questão  é o que seria exatamente o **Spring MVC**. Quais suas principais características?
Gostaria de uma pequena explicação sobre as principais características.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Spring MVC é um framework JAVA, que implementa o design pattern MVC.

Suas principais características podem ser visualizadas [aqui](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/overview.html#overview-modules)

Entre elas existem:

[Injeção de dependencia](http://www.devmedia.com.br/padrao-de-injecao-de-dependencia/18506)

[Programação orientada a aspecto incluindo gerenciamento de transações declarativas do Spring](http://www.devmedia.com.br/introducao-a-programacao-orientada-a-aspectos-conceitos/3062)

MVC para aplicações WEB e web service RESTFul

Suporte para JDBC, JPA, JMS

Fonte: http://projects.spring.io/spring-framework/

Comment: cara só faltou uma breve descrição de cada uma brother!! Apenas algumas palavras , Ok?

Comment: Eu linkei os topicos em alguns artigos bacanas explicativos. ^^